# In-App Browser not opening external links

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, inappbrowser

## Background

I have an app build via Ionic 4 (w/ Angular) calling the Cordova in-app browser plugin. After the splash screen, the in-app browser loads a URL that is a mobile-responsive website.

This website has urls such as:

- domain.com/somepath
- domain.com/somepath/somepage.html
- domain.com/somefilename.pdf
- someotherdomain.com

The links that refer to `someotherdomain.com` or `domain.com/somefilename.pdf` typically have `target="_blank"` within the mobile-responsive html code.

## Issue

As it stand now (testing via iOS), the in-app browser will not open any of the `target="_blank"` urls.

## What I've tried

I've tried different settings and parameters, `console.log()`, and testing via `ionic cordova build ios --prod`, `ionic serve` and `ionic cordova run browser`.

```
  openWebpage(url: string) {
    const options : InAppBrowserOptions = {
        location                            : 'yes' 
        ,footer                             : 'no'
        ,hidenavigationbuttons              : 'yes'
        ,hidden                             : 'no'  
        ,hideurlbar                         : 'no'
        ,useWideViewPort                    : 'yes'
        //,clearsessioncache                : 'yes' 
        //,cleardata                        : 'yes'
        //,clearcache                       : 'yes' 
        ,zoom                               : 'no'            // Android only, shows browser zoom controls
        ,hardwareback                       : 'no'  
        ,mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction    : 'no'  
        ,shouldPauseOnSuspend               : 'no'            // Android only
        ,closebuttoncaption                 : 'Close'         // iOS only
        ,disallowoverscroll                 : 'no'            // iOS only
        ,toolbar                            : 'yes'           // iOS only
        ,enableViewportScale                : 'yes'           // iOS only
        ,allowInlineMediaPlayback           : 'yes'           // iOS only
        ,presentationstyle                  : 'fullscreen'    // iOS only
        ,usewkwebview                       : 'no'
        ,toolbarposition                    : 'top'
        ,fullscreen                         : 'yes'           // Windows only
    };

 
    const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(url,'_self',options);
```

## Question

How can I:

- do some type of `window.alert()` for every href link click done via in-app browser (for debugging more easily)?
- cause external links to open in a system browser (right now, nothing happens when they are clicked)?

Comment: Remove the Plugin, refer Ionic framework site and install the plugin and Node module . Once the plugin installed successfully, try to open www.google.com and if it opens successfully you can make sure that the inapp browser is working well .

Answer (score 1):

InAppBrowser uses **_blank** to open url if its listed in `whitelist`. i'd suggest to use Apache [Cordova Whitelist Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) to whitelist the URLs you want to open.

1. add Cordova plugin

   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`
2. in `config.xml` add `<allow-intent>` tags with URLs, like

   `<allow-intent href="http://example.com/*" />`

Comment: The whitelist plugin is already installed. here is a sample from my config.xml .            <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="*domain.com*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="*onedomain.com*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="*twodomain.com" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="*threedomain.com*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="content:///*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />

Comment: @MichaelAmburgey how do we add whitelist plugin with capacitor, im working with latest ionic and im using capacitor instead of cordova